# Get a single character from a char* in C

Tags: c, string, char

Is there a way to traverse character by character or extract a single character from char* in C?

Consider the following code. Now which is the best way to get individual characters?
Suggest me a method without using any             string functions.

```
char *a = "STRING";
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Another way:

```
char * i;

for (i=a; *i; i++) {
   // i points successively to a[0], a[1], ... until a '\0' is observed.
}
```

Comment: Indeed, but you need to then explicitly dereference `i` inside your `for` loop which you don't need to do with `a[foo]`. This could muddy the answer for a beginner.

Comment: It can be superior to other ways because no extra addition occurs.

With `a[i]`, there is always the addition `a+i`, where `a` is a pointer and `i` an integer. This is inferior to just `i++` where `i` is a pointer if `a[i]` resp. `*i` is used multiple times inside the loop.

But this is micro-optimization.

Comment: a[foo] is shorthand for *(a+foo).  In learning C, it's important that a student recognize that, except for the declaration, using array subscripts and pointer arithmetic are equivalent.  +1

Comment: If you're that worried about micro-optimizing I'd suggest to use `++i` preincrement not `i++` postincrement ;)

Comment: Sometimes ++i will be less efficient.

Comment: @Arafangion: nonsense. Why on earth would a C implementer go out of their way to create that difference between the two?

Comment: @Arafangion Not true in the case of a for loop. The compiler is smart enough to make optimizations on this. ++i is also the more efficient one in most cases because it doesn't create a copy of i.

Comment: @MGZero: "++i is also the more efficient one" also nonsense. This is C, not C++, and there's absolutely no need for a compiler to make an unused copy of the prior value of `i`. `++i` could only be more efficient if "most cases" if most code is very feebly optimized, but closely considering the performance of unoptimized code is fairly futile. In C++ it's true that for user-defined types, the optimization is a little harder in general and sometimes actually impossible.

Comment: @Steve Jessop You do realize I was agreeing with you, right?  Second, I had already noted that the compiler makes optimizations in the cases where the post-increment copy is not needed such as in the case of a for loop.  Reading my post over now though, it does sound like I meant something else...

Comment: Why does the for loop terminate when `*(i+1) = '\0'`? Is it because `'\0'` causes the condition to fail?

Comment: @MinhTran It should not do so. It should only terminate if `*i` is `\0`, for obvious reasons (`\0` is the null byte, which is `== 0` and evaluates to false in boolean contexts).

Answer (score 5):

Knowing the length of the char array, you can cycle through it with a for loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < myStringLen; i++)
{
     if (a[i] == someChar)
        //do something
}
```

Remember, a char * can be used as a C-Style string.  And a string is just an array of characters, so you can just index it.

EDIT: Because I was asked on the comments, see section 5.3.2 of this link for details on arrays and pointers:
http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter5/pointers.html

Comment: There are many char*'s that can't be used as  C-style string.  A 'char*' might be pointing to a single char, or a block of data, or anything, really.

Comment: That still doesn't stop you from indexing it.

Comment: It does, if it only points to a single char. In that context, it might be nonsensical to talk about it in terms of "indexing".

Comment: Well, we're not talking about that context, now are we?  The original question specifically asked about a string.

Comment: But you are when you say: "Remember, a char * can be used as a C-Style string".

Comment: @Arafangion Also, for the record, I just tested it with a single char and you can still index it. VC++ 2010. I can send you the code if you'd like.

Comment: Yes.  What about this code? for(int i=0; i[a]; ++i) { if (i[a] == someChar) {...}}.   And no, that is NOT a mistake.  Does this "prove" that I can index i with a?  In this situation, all you are saying is that you can do pointer arithmetic with a 'char *', which happens to be a pointer, so there are no surprises there.

Comment: int main() { char * myTest = new char; myTest[0] = 's'; std::cout << "Value of my test at 0: " << myTest[0] << "\n"; system("Pause"); delete myTest; return 0; } (Sorry for the formatting, I really don't know how to format it in comments).) You specifically said it couldn't be indexed. So I indexed it with 0. You never specified with what. Indexing char * i with int a can fail in ANY situation regardless of whether or not it's a C-Style string.

Comment: I would also like to add that yes, I am getting at pointer arithmetic. Why wouldn't I be? It's synonymous with indexing, the compiler outputs the same thing for both of them.  By saying I can do pointer arithmetic on this, you've pretty much agreed with me.

Comment: Except that it's not exactly the same, and it's confusing to newbies that they are different. It's better to show them arrays, and to show them pointers, then to consider how arrays are typically implemented. Consider that the sizeof operator differs on arrays vs pointers.

Comment: Except they are the same as far as the compiler is concerned. http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter5/pointers.html See section 5.3.2, example 5.3 (read the above paragraph). Also, I showed arrays did I not? I didn't even mention pointer arithmetic until you brought it up.

Comment: That's a good link, put that into the answer and I'll upvote you. :)

Answer (score 4):

```
size_t i;
for (i=0; a[i]; i++) {
    /* do something with a[i] */
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Like this.

```
char       a1[] = "STRING";
const char * a2 = "STRING";

char * c;     /* or "const char" for a2 */

for (c = aN; *c; ++c)
{
  /* *c is the character */
}
```

Here `N` can be `1` or `2`. For `a1` you can modify the characters, for `a2` you cannot. Note that assigning a string literal to a `char*` is deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

```
int i=0;
while(a[i]!=0)/* or a[i]!='\0' */
{
   // do something to a[i]
   ++i;
}
```

EDIT:

You can also use `strlen(a)` to get the number of characters in `a`.

Comment: Wouldn't that while loop go out of bounds?

Comment: No, but as it was it wouldn't have moved on from the zeroth character. Edited to include `++i` now though.

Comment: And it still won't go out of bounds because C strings are null terminated.