# Reading character by character from a string in C

Tags: c, xcode, string

I am trying to read character by character from a string in my xcode porgram on C. Can this be done on C because I can't seem to find any function as to how to do it..

For example:

If I were to read character by character from:

```
char* name= "Mario";
```

How can this be done? Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get a single character from a char\* in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7040501/get-a-single-character-from-a-char-in-c)

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 ways to iterate over null-terminated char array (string) of unknown length :

```
for (char *ch = name; *ch; ++ch) {
    // *ch is the current char
}

for (int i=0; name[i]; ++i) {
    // name[i] is the current char and i the index
}
```

If the length is not known you can get it with `strlen` and use it in the second for loop as a limit for `i`. But `strlen` will iterate itself over the char array to find the null terminating and that's wasteful.

Answer (score 1):

Just index it like an array, e.g. `char x = name[0]; /* sets x to 'M' */`

And remember, there will be a null terminator at the end of the string. The null terminator compares equal to 0.